# Path to module is listed on sys.path but I'm unable to import it

Tags: python, import, pythonpath, sys.path, import-module

I have a folder at this path /Users/felipeformenti/cortex/dev/ds_tools
I have an `__init__.py` inside of this folder
The folder is listed on my sys.path
And still I'm unable to import this module

What am I  missing???

[image]

Comment: Add the path one level up from `ds_tools`:  `sys.path.append('/Users/felipeformenti/cortex/dev')`

Comment: Also check your init file name: should be `__init__.py`  (your underscores may be hidden here by markdown formatting)

Comment: I believe that there are underscores, double underscores around a word makes it __bold__ in markdown

Comment: Thanks @AbbeGijly you solved it. And yes I had double underscores but that was interpreted as bold

Comment: Please copy paste your error tracebacks or code in text form, in future posts.